# mysql dynamic query inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I wrote the following dynamic query in my stored procedure,

```
FETCH cur1 INTO a1, ldt1, b1;
    WHILE DONE = 0 DO

        SET @s=CONCAT('UPDATE ',fname , ' SET connectedDateTime = ldt1,opid = b1 
        WHERE hq_conferee_seqno=a1 AND (LoggedDateTime <=ldt1 AND connectedDateTime IS NULL)');
        FETCH cur1 INTO a1, ldt1, b1;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
    END WHILE; 
    CLOSE cur1;
```

When I compile the stored I am not getting any error. But When I run this code I got an error like You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

What will be the problem. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> Local variables are in scope only during stored program execution. References to them are not permitted within prepared statements because those are global to the current session and the variables might have gone out of scope when the statement is executed.

You should instead fetch your cursor into *user* variables and either reference those from the prepared statement (they remain in scope for the duration of the connection), or (better yet) pass them to the prepared statement as parameters:

```
SET @s=CONCAT('UPDATE ',fname , ' SET connectedDateTime = ?,opid = ? 
WHERE hq_conferee_seqno=? AND (LoggedDateTime <=? AND connectedDateTime IS NULL)');
FETCH cur1 INTO @a1, @ldt1, @b1;
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt USING @ldt1, @b1, @a1, @ldt1;
```